# Understand proof involving convolution and integration

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm currently trying to understand the following proof but there are some obscurities

[image]

From the second to the third line, why does $\int_\mathbb{R^n}|f(y)|\Big(\int_{\mathbb{R^n}}|g(x-y)|dx\Big)dy$ equal $\int_\mathbb{R^n}|f(y)|dy\int_{\mathbb{R^n}}|g(x)|dx$?

And here I don't understand why $\int_{\mathbb{R^n}}|g(x-y)|dy^{1/p'}=\|g\|_1^{1/p'}$ from the third to last line [image]

Answer (score 1):

To the first question: 
This is the change of variables $x\mapsto x-y$, indeed, 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x-y)\mathrm dx =\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)\mathrm dx
$$
For the second, this is the definition of the $L^1$ norm, 
$$
||g||_1=\int_{-\infty}^\infty |g(x)|\mathrm dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty |g(x-y)|\mathrm dx
$$

Answer (score 0):

It’s actually rather easy: just notice that the integral is over $y$ and the whole space, so shifting it by $x$ won’t make any difference. (In other words, you can replace $x-y$ by $y$).

Once you have done that, it’s just a matter of definition.

Answer (score 0):

The same argument for both the questions: $\int h(x+a) \, dx=\int h(x) \, dx$ for any integrable function $h$ and any $a \in \mathbb R^{n}$.